# Highlight row on selected ( apex repeat )

Tags: apex, visualforce, table, repeat

I need to highlight the row on click of anchor link.

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!Requests}" var="request">
                                <tr>

                                    <td><a onclick="sendRequestId('{!request.Id}');"> {!request.Subject} </a></td>
                                    <td>{!request.Type}</td>
                                    <td>{!request.Location__r.Name}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" >
                                            <apex:param value="{!request.CreatedDate}"/>
                                        </apex:outputText>
                                    </td>

                               </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted so far? Do you want this to be a non-jQuery solution?

Comment: For jQuery, just google and find something like [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287699/jquery-highlight-de-highlight-table-row-on-click) and then [jQuery in a Visualforce Page](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible non-jQuery solution:

```
<script>
    function findParent(el, tagName) {
        tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
        do {
            el = el.parentNode;
            if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagName) {
                return el;
            }
        } while (el.parentNode);

        return null;
    }

    function highlight(element, tagName) {
        if (element && tagName) {
            var thingToHighlight = findParent(element, tagName);
            if (thingToHighlight) {
                thingToHighlight.style = 'background-color: yellow';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Your hyperlink likely needs an `href` attribute which I've added to the example. I've then added another function to perform the highlighting of the closest parent `tr` element with a yellow background. The `onclick` function might need to `return false;` depending on the behavior you're expecting from the click of the link.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Requests}" var="request">
<tr>

    <td><a href="#" onclick="sendRequestId('{!request.Id}'); highlight(this, 'tr');"> {!request.Subject} </a></td>
    <td>{!request.Type}</td>
    <td>{!request.Location__r.Name}</td>
    <td>
        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" >
            <apex:param value="{!request.CreatedDate}"/>
        </apex:outputText>
    </td>

</tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning jQuery in a "you don't need jQuery to do this" kind of way. jQuery, while great for large applications, is little more than a crutch in Visualforce, unless you're actually leveraging a large portion of the library.

Comment: @Mark Pond ..Its not highlighting the selected the row.I have added alert statement on javascript.. thingToHighlight = [object HTMLTableRowElement]

Comment: I'm not sure why it's relevent how much of jQuery one would use.  If you're already writing javascript why write methods to select a parent element when you could be using a tested, cross-browser library like jQuery which exists to do exactly that?

Comment: @PhilR Some people can't or don't want to introduce the jQuery library into their environment. Just presenting alternatives.

Comment: @sf.dev can you update your question with your complete updated markup rather than just the snippit with the repeat tag?